# Is there any reason to use Python's generator-based coroutines over async/await?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, generator, coroutine

Despite its well-known "one way to do it" philosophy, Python (as of version 3.5) supports two ways of writing coroutines:

1. [enhanced generators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/) (perhaps with [`yield from`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/))
2. [`async` and `await`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/).

Assume we only need to support versions of Python >= 3.5. Is it ever necessary to use the older, generator-based coroutines? Or do `async`/`await`-based coroutines completely replace generator-based ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [Guido van Rossum himself](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2015-April/139728.html):

> [...] eventually we'll always be using async functions when coroutines are called for, dedicating generators once again to their pre-PEP-342 role of a particularly efficient way to implement iterators.